# Can't style cells in specific table

Tags: html, css

```
.domeSpecs
{
font-size: 16px;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
float: right;
border-collapse: collapse;
background-image: url('tableback.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right bottom;
}

table.domeSpecs>td
{
color: blue;
}
```

I'm trying to style only the cells within the table with the class domeSpecs with the font color of blue (just to test if it works), but it isn't working for some reason.

Comment: We'll need to see your HTML too. Please put your affected code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: table.domeSpecs > tr > td? Direct descendant is being used, but there's probably a row in between.

Comment: @jwinn I only just saw that too! -_- but depending on structure, may need to be `.domeSpecs > tbody > tr > td` ...

Comment: please show some HTML.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table.domeSpecs>td` is accessing the **immediate descendant** `TD`

shoud be `TR` so:

```
table.domeSpecs > tr > td
```

which is also strange unless you have to recognize tables that have a `TR` as immediate instead of i.e: `tbody` ... So my suggestion is: keep it simple:

```
table.domeSpecs  td{

}
```

**IF you have CELLS with `class` .domeSpecs** all you need is:

```
table td.domeSpecs{

}
```

Comment: @aarocard try harder ;)

Comment: @popnoodles I suspect his CSS is quite large and messy, so a `color:blue !important;` might be one of the possible (also messy) solutions.

Comment: @Roko Actually that's all the CSS in the document at the moment. Isn't table.domeSpecs td a rule stating to style a table with class domeSpecs and all td elements (including ones in other tables)?

Comment: Regardless though table.domeSpecs td seems to work fine. I'm just trying to figure out why it wasn't working using the element.class>element selectors

Comment: Nevermind I was getting selectors mixed up. It works!